# Can I Automatically Create UUID on GraphQL Mutation?

Tags: typescript, graphql

I setup apollo server and used type-graphql to connect to postgres database. I have the following query:

```
mutation Mutation($data: ClickInput!) {
  createClick(data: $data) {
    id
    clickId    
  }
}
```

and I pass the data:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "id": "",
    "clickId": "Tester123#xyz",
    "url": "#",
    "utm_source": "", 
    "device":"device"
  }
}
```

I cannot seem to find out how to automatically generate the UUID. Do I do that on the client-side or server-side and does it go in the controller, entity, or service?

Screenshot of my Apollo Sandbox:

[image]

Comment: In a lot of cases your DB generates the ID, but i am not familiar with Postgres. If not then i recommend to generate it in your Repository/Entity-Layer.

Comment: usually ... input type for create mutations shouldn't contain `id` field (like in sql insert) ... if not required for some reasons ... id can be generated [natively] on db (if required id type supported) or on orm/resolver level

Comment: Generate ID’s server side otherwise you will cause components to re-render.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I removed it from the mutations and postgres does generate uuid's so I am almost there.

Comment: It says the ID is required.  Does that come from type-graphql?  I think I might be out of my depth with typescript and class decorators but I will try to remove the InputType for ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could make a UUID automatically with graphql, but I am using nestjs and mysql with graphql.

first,

```
import { GraphQLScalarType } from 'graphql';
```

Then I adapted a function to generate a UUID, this is the funtion:

```
const UUID_2 = () => {
  const caracteres = 
    'abcdefghijkmnpqrtuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKMNPQRTUVWXYZ012346789';
    let UUID_2 = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      UUID_2 += caracteres.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 
      caracteres.length));
  }
   console.log(UUID_2); // this is to test
   return UUID_2;
};
```

In my case I needed to generate a four character uuid, so you can adapt the function to your needs.

After that use the method or function that imports in a new function:

```
export const CustomUuidScalar = new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'UUID',
  description: 'A simple UUID parser',
  serialize: () => UUID_2(),
  parseValue: () => UUID_2(),
  parseLiteral: () => UUID_2(),
});
```

Output Sample:

```
A3yt,
1UQj
```

I based my code on the official nestjs and graphql documentation. Here is the link: https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/scalars.

You should import in your app module and in your entity class.

Comment: With Typescript and Prisma this was a lot easier, but I reverted to GraphQLScalarType because I think it is a much cleaner solution.